# Bonsai related - Moujean Tea vs Fukien Tea (are they the same?)

Tags: identification, bonsai

Are they the same or in the same family? even the fruits look identical... and their branches and plant shape are the same too... I was given a bonsai and thought it was Moujean Tea, but after spotting the same plant all over Singapore as weed, I decided to pay the plant nursery a visit and they labelled it as Fukien Tea...

Nashia inaguensis (commonly referred to as Moujean tea, Bahamas berry, or pineapple verbena)
[image]

Carmona retusa (also known as the Fukien tea tree or Philippine tea tree)
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No they are not the same - the evidence is in the Latin names. The Latin or botanical name of a plant IS its name - any common epithets such as fukien tea or aunt jane's tea or fred's plant are not terribly helpful for identifying a plant because they are common names. Common names may differ from region to region and country to country, so knowing the proper Latin name is critical for correct ID.

Despite any superficial similarity you may see, Carmona belongs to the Boraginaceae, and Nashia to the Verbenaceae, two entirely separate plant Families.

Comment: Thanks Bamboo. Sadly, my Carmona retusa shared the same trait as Nashia 'I dry I die'..............

Comment: You have my sympathy - I'm no good with keeping bonsai either...